# adding redirect url to springboot service running in prod

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have spring boot MVC application running in production, its endpoint is http://example.or/api/operation1 , and want to also support end point http://example.or/api/operation1/ , what do I do without code change so that my service can respond to both url, with and without / at the end.

Service is containerized, and deployed using openshift.

Looking for any configuration option that can save me from going through deployment and allow client access immediately.

Comment: assuming you are using a reverse proxy like `nginx`, add a rule to redirect all traffic that starts with `/api/operation1` to the app